# php parse error syntax error unexpected t_string

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'am getting the following error: "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'qtip' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in your code on line 14" in this code:

```
<?php
// Always use wp_enqueue_scripts action hook to both enqueue and register scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_and_register_qtip_scripts_and_style' );

function enqueue_and_register_qtip_scripts_and_style(){

    // Use `get_stylesheet_directoy_uri() if your script is inside your theme or child theme.
    wp_register_style( 'qtip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/jquery.qtip.min.css', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'imagesloaded', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/imagesloaded.pkg.min.js', true );    
    wp_register_script( 'qtip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/jquery.qtip.min.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded'), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min), false, true );

// Add the styles first, in the <head> (last parameter false, true = bottom of page!)
   wp_enqueue_style( 'qtip', null, false, false );

// Using imagesLoaded? Do this.
wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded', null, false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'qtip', false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tooltip', false, true );
}
?>
```

The 14 line says: " wp_enqueue_style( 'qtip', null, false, false ); "

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should use a code editor with syntax highlighting. It'll show you **EXACTLY** where the colors go wrong, which is where you've got your missing `'`. Since it's a simple typo, voting to close. e.g. look at the code here and see where it goes all-red.

Comment: looks like you are missing a ' after jquery-qtip-min),false,true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `'`  `(single quote)` in this line after `jquery-qtip-min`

```
 wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min), false, true );
```

should be

```
wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min'), false, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
    wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js',    array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min), false, true );
```

is missing a quote on the `jquery-qtip-min` param

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min), false, true );
```

A single ' is missing after jquery-qtip-min on this line.